# Windows Event_System_Foreground delivery order

Tags: windows, winapi

Working in a plugin architecture (specifically, Sparx Systems Enterprise Architect), which does not forward either raw or cooked keyboard events, keyboard shortcuts for the plugin can be defined using [RegisterHotKey()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309(v=vs.85).aspx). These hotkeys are global, and the registration call fails if the specified key combination is already registered.

Since the application within which the plugin executes can be run in multiple instances, the hotkeys need to be repeatedly registered and unregistered based on which instance is in the foreground. An [event hook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd373640%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for [EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318066(v=vs.85).aspx#EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND) can be set up for this purpose, but the question is: is there a guaranteed delivery order?

I need the instance that is losing focus to be told first so that it can unregister the hotkeys before the instance gaining focus tries to register them.

Is this possible? Or will I have to implement synchronization to be sure?

Answer (score 0):

[Windows DevCenter WM_ACTIVATE message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646274(v=vs.85).aspx) says

> ..Sent to both the window being activated and the window being deactivated. If the windows use the same input queue, the message is sent synchronously, first to the window procedure of the top-level window being deactivated, then to the window procedure of the top-level window being activated. If the windows use different input queues, the message is sent asynchronously, so the window is activated immediately..

So if all of your windows come from the same application sharing the same input queue then it should be guaranteed. I guess that the `EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND` is built on top of the older code following the older logic (at least the implementation in ReactOS at http://svn.reactos.org/svn/reactos/trunk/reactos/win32ss/user/ntuser/focus.c?view=markup (see EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND inside co_IntSetActiveWindow) does it)

Your problem might be easier if you'd monitor only keyboard events in your original hosting process (no global side effects) using the [Windows DevCenter SetWindowsHookEx function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx), filter `WH_KEYBOARD`

In that case your code would exist once in one exe having one global variables, no cross-process synchronization would be needed